# Are transition matrices and markov chains considered a part of time series analysis

Tags: time-series, markov-process, transition-matrix

Is the topic of Markov Process and Transition Matrices considered a part of time series analysis? Transition matrix has the intuition of being a time based process because the transition probabilities are w.r.t time periods.

So are transition matrices considered time series analysis. I ask because I could not find them in a book on machine learning, so was wondering what kind of book should cover this topic?

Comment: The usual "go to" by James Hamilton - "Time Series Analysis" - covers this. Also featured in Kim and Nelson's "State-Space Models with Regime Switching". You will find treatments in other fields, too; for example, see Ljungqvist and Sargent's "[Recursive Macroeconomic Theory](http://www.econ.yale.edu/smith/econ510a/sargent3.pdf)" - Chapter 2. A decent undergraduate linear algebra book should also touch on this material.